# To get a .jar file

Tags: java, jar

I read a post on your forum where it told to me using this procedure to get a .jar file but it doesn't work on my pc.

I have these two class:

```
Main.java

package somma;

public class Main extends Somma {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 1;
        int b = 2;
        int s = somma(a, b);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}

Somma.java

package somma;

public class Somma {
    public static int somma(int a, int b) {
        int s = a + b;
        return s;
    }
}
```

and I would to get a .jar file to write one class alone of this type:

```
MainCheUsaLaLibreria.java

package t; //This is into new project!

public class MainCheUsaLaLibreria {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 1;
        int b = 2;
        int s = somma(a, b);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Is it possible, how I can do to get working .jar file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear enough, I understand you are trying to package your classes into a jar file and use it other java program.

If so, you can use command line tool "jar" to create the file:

> jar cvx somma.jar somma

(assuming you have compiled both classes)
Tools like ant, maven or Eclipse IDE are really helpful to compile and build the jar file.

Then add it to the classpath on the project (MainCheUsaLaLibreria) and import your classes from the jar file.

Comment: While you wrote I solved the problem by myself, thank you very much and I am sorry for the inconvenience.